# I am comparing 2 sets of integer values from 2 saparate arrays

Tags: java, arrays, loops

Can anyone please help. I  am comparing 2 sets of lottery numbers the userNumbers being the numbers from your ticket and the numbers array representing numbers from the lottery draw on the website. When I run the program and type in the 6 correct numbers the program informs me I have won the jackpot. However if I have any less than 6 numbers matching I am stuck in a while loop. can anyone help me to get out of this so that if I match 2 numbers the program will inform me ive matched 2 nos, if I match 3 it will inform me of this and so on! and if I match the bonus the program will inform me I have matched the bonus and (n) amount of numbers.
I am quite new to Java and have been mulling over this for some time! Thanks in advance!

```
final int SIZE = 6;
         //array to store user numbers
         int [] userNumbers = new int[SIZE];
         boolean found = false;
         int pos = 0;
         boolean bonus = false;
         int lottCount = 0;
         boolean jackpot;

         while (pos<SIZE)
         {
            System.out.println("enter your numbers");
            userNumbers[pos]=keyboard.nextInt();
            pos++;
         }
         for (int count: userNumbers)
         {
            System.out.println(count);
         }

         for (int loop = 0; loop <SIZE; loop++ )
         {
            for (int loopOther = 0; loopOther < numbers.length; loopOther++)
            {
               if (userNumbers[loop] == numbers[loopOther])
               {
                  lottCount++;
               } else if (userNumbers[loop] == bonusBall)
                        {
                           bonus = true;
                        }
            }//for

         }//forMain

         if (lottCount == 6)
         {
            jackpot = true;
            System.out.println("You have matched all numbers!! Congratulations you are a jackpot winner");
         }else System.out.println(" You have matched " + lottCount + " numbers. Please visit the webpage did you see what you have won");
         while (lottCount < 6)

         if  (bonus)
           {
                  System.out.println("You have matched " + lottCount + " numbers " + "and" + " the bonus ball"
                          + bonusBall + " Please see the website to check your prize.");
           } else
                  System.out.println("You have not won at this time. ");
```

Comment: "*I am stuck in a while loop.*" How? Please explain.

Comment: Would be due to the code `while (lottCount < 6)` at the end. What is that supposed to do? At the moment it makes sure you get stuck in a while loop if you haven't matched 6 numbers.

Comment: i tried while (lottCount < 6) && (lottCount != 0) but java doesnt allow me to use the && operator for doing this

Comment: try to expand a loop, so it's able to get matches.

Answer (score 1):

looks like "while (lottCount < 6)" is unnecessary, take that out and it should work, looks like you want something along the lines of:

```
if (lottCount == 6) {
    System.out.println("You have matched all numbers!! Congratulations you are a jackpot winner");
} 
else if (!bonus) {
    System.out.println(" You have matched " + lottCount + " numbers. Please visit the webpage did you see what you have won");
}

if  (bonus) {
      System.out.println("You have matched " + lottCount + " numbers " + "and" + " the bonus ball"
          + bonusBall + " Please see the website to check your prize.");
}
```